# Line break based on character found

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel, line-breaks, word-wrap

I want to break an email in a UILabel into two lines by "@" , for example:

```
abc123
@gmail.com
```

If the word is inside a NSString *variable, how can I break it? Should I search the string by character until I found "@"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of `components(separatedBy separator: String) -> [String]` function on `String`:

**Swift**:

```
let stringComponentsArray = yourString.components(separatedBy: "@")
```

**Objective-C**:

```
NSArray *stringComponentsArray = [yourStringObject componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
```

This will separate your string by a character *@* into a `String` components *array*.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! By the way, is there any other method else? eg: NSLineBreak or Wrapping etc..

Comment: No problem! I'm not aware of any other method that would solve your problem with greater ease than ``componentsSeparatedByString:``.